# How to reproduce Java OutOfMemoryError - GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

My approach was to create hundred thousand local collections and populate them with random strings, something like this:

```
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i++){
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 30 ; j++){
            map.put(new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32), new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32));
        }
    }
```

I have provided -XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit jvm parameter too, but can not get the error. Is there any easy and reliable way/hack to get this error?

Comment: Save the maps inside another collection that is declared outside the `for` loops and add a `while(true)` before the first `for` loop.

Comment: Good question! It is easy enough to reproduce a "heap OOM", but reproducing the overhead limit is MUCH trickier... I wonder if it is even possible! (purposefully, that is)

Comment: Make outer for loop as while(true) this is reproduce the error.

Comment: @StephenC - Yes,100% true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you haven't accepted any answer, I'll assume that none of them have worked for you. Here's one that will. But first, a review of [the conditions that trigger this error](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#par_gc.oom):

> The parallel collector will throw an OutOfMemoryError if too much time is being spent in garbage collection: if more than 98% of the total time is spent in garbage collection and less than 2% of the heap is recovered

So, you have to consume almost all of the heap, keep it allocated, and then allocate lots of garbage. Putting lots of stuff into a `Map` isn't going to do this for you.

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
throws Exception
{
    List<Object> fixedData = consumeAvailableMemory();
    while (true)
    {
        Object data = new byte[64 * 1024 - 1];
    }
}


private static List<Object> consumeAvailableMemory()
throws Exception
{
    LinkedList<Object> holder = new LinkedList<Object>();
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            holder.add(new byte[128 * 1024]);
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError ex)
        {
            holder.removeLast();
            return holder;
        }
    }
}
```

The `consumeAvailableMemory()` method fills up the heap with relatively small chunks of memory. "Relatively small" is important because the JVM will put "large" objects (512k bytes in my experience) directly into the tenured generation, leaving the young generation empty.

After I've consumed most of the heap, I just allocate and discard. The smaller block size in this phase is important: I know that I'll have enough memory for at least one allocation, but probably not more than two. This will keep the GC active.

Running this produces the desired error in under a second:

```
> java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m GCOverheadTrigger
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at GCOverheadTrigger.main(GCOverheadTrigger.java:12)
```

And, for completeness, here's the JVM that I'm using:

```
> java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

And now my question for you: why in the world would you want to do this?

Comment: +1 for a very nice way of permanently consuming *nearly* all the memory, in order to reproduce.

Comment: Answering your question: wanted to test if JVM can still somehow recover from this state, maybe with some help of supervisor or other service. To be honest I also do not get the point of this exception since JVM become unresponsive soon after this exception. I would rather expect JVM to terminate (fail fast approach).

Comment: @mkorszun - that's really the point of the exception: shut the JVM down rather than keep trying to free up space. Like most OOM errors, it indicates that you haven't allocated enough heap to run your program (sometimes "enough" is infinite, but more often the program has a real upper bound that it needs). The one time that I saw this error in a real program, we were maintaining a large set of objects that would be updated by incoming messages. The messages were short-lived, so would be constantly collected. The error went away when we increased the heap.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

is scoped *within* the loop and there are no external (long-term) references to the map created as the loop iterates. Hence each map will be eligible for garbage collection at the end of each loop iteration.

You need to create a collection of objects *outside* the loop, and use the loop to populate that collection.

Comment: Although that would certainly trigger a "heap OOM", not an overhead limit, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick ... if you run it long enough:

```
HashMap<Long, String> map = new HashMap<Long, String>();
for (long i = 0; true; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        String s = "" + j;
        map.put(i, s);
    }
}
```

What I'm doing is slowly building up the amount of the non-garbage, while creating a significant amount of garbage at the same time.  If this is run until the non-garbage fills nearly all of the heap, the GC will get to a point where the % of time spent garbage collecting exceeds the threshold.

Comment: it still throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Increase the loop counter for the inner loop.

Comment: I guess you can always `-Xmx8M` if you want to shorten the running time ;)

Comment: Nah ... if you are intent on *torturing* a JVM, you should *prolong* the pain as much as possible.  ;-)

Comment: Couldn’t get the gc activity above 20% with this code. I think, it’s producing too much garbage, compared to the survivors, which is actually good for modern gc algorithms. Further, there are too little changes of the old generation here. I think, a good way to torture the JVM, is an approach like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49819738/2711488). It may get augmented with some removals once a certain heap occupancy has been reached and then, should produce “overhead limit exceeded” reliably, if such a limit has been configured.