# How to make a long time Full GC in Java manually

Tags: java, garbage-collection

How to write some code to allocate the objects into Old Gen that will cause the full GC time longer than three or five seconds?

Comment: Why don't you just ask your question? You're falling victim to [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Allocate the objects into Old Gen” and “long GC pauses” are hard to combine, as the worst thing you could do to the garbage collector, is to create lots of small, linked, live objects forming a graph that the garbage collector must traverse.

But small objects are not allocated into the Old Gen. Only large objects, e.g. arrays, are allocated directly into the Old Gen, but these do not stress the GC that much. Especially primitive type arrays, which you stated to have been used in your first attempt, are no challenge, as they can not contain object references in general.

So, to stress the GC, you have to create lots of small linked objects, enough to get them eventually promoted to the Old Gen, followed by modifying the old objects to enforce Full GC, resp. updates of the remembered sets of the affected cards.

If that’s sounds like familiar pattern, you’re right. We’re talking about `LinkedList` here.

```
LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();
for(ListIterator<Object> it = list.listIterator();;) {
    for(;;) {
        it.add(new Object());
        if(!it.hasNext()) break;
        it.next();
    }
    while(it.hasPrevious()) {
        it.previous();
        it.add(new Object());
        it.previous();
    }
}
```

This iterates over the list back and forth, inserting new objects between the old ones, which implies modifying the [`next`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedList.java#972) pointer of the preceding and the `prev` pointer of the succeeding list node. We have to do this via `ListIterator`, as trying to use `add(int index, E element)` would become too slow for a growing linked list, not creating enough objects to stress the GC.

Running on Java 9.0.4 with `-Xmx7G -Xlog:gc` gave me

```
[0.023s][info][gc] Using G1
[0.230s][info][gc] GC(0) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 24M->22M(256M) 60.748ms
[0.263s][info][gc] GC(1) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 34M->36M(256M) 21.686ms
[0.299s][info][gc] GC(2) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 46M->47M(256M) 18.848ms
[0.336s][info][gc] GC(3) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 57M->58M(256M) 20.904ms
[0.391s][info][gc] GC(4) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 68M->68M(768M) 31.420ms
[0.521s][info][gc] GC(5) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 104M->105M(768M) 56.681ms
[0.620s][info][gc] GC(6) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 138M->140M(768M) 46.616ms
[0.737s][info][gc] GC(7) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 173M->174M(768M) 58.947ms
[0.906s][info][gc] GC(8) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 207M->209M(2304M) 100.361ms
[1.272s][info][gc] GC(9) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 319M->321M(2304M) 142.440ms
[1.656s][info][gc] GC(10) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 421M->423M(2304M) 162.770ms
[1.992s][info][gc] GC(11) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 523M->525M(2304M) 145.804ms
[2.404s][info][gc] GC(12) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 625M->627M(4250M) 221.090ms
[3.088s][info][gc] GC(13) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 824M->826M(4250M) 302.307ms
[3.721s][info][gc] GC(14) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 1011M->1013M(4250M) 250.395ms
[4.421s][info][gc] GC(15) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 1198M->1199M(4250M) 304.642ms
[5.179s][info][gc] GC(16) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 1384M->1386M(5418M) 334.825ms
[6.134s][info][gc] GC(17) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 1629M->1631M(5418M) 381.155ms
[6.897s][info][gc] GC(18) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 1867M->1868M(5418M) 309.688ms
[7.670s][info][gc] GC(19) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 2104M->2106M(5418M) 399.689ms
[8.498s][info][gc] GC(20) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 2342M->2344M(6118M) 388.430ms
[9.515s][info][gc] GC(21) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 2615M->2617M(6118M) 439.557ms
[10.477s][info][gc] GC(22) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 2883M->2884M(6118M) 451.488ms
[11.489s][info][gc] GC(23) Pause Initial Mark (G1 Evacuation Pause) 3150M->3152M(6118M) 443.329ms
[11.489s][info][gc] GC(24) Concurrent Cycle
[12.660s][info][gc] GC(25) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 3418M->3419M(6538M) 467.964ms
[14.124s][info][gc] GC(26) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 3706M->3708M(6538M) 454.921ms
[15.538s][info][gc] GC(27) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 3993M->3995M(6538M) 465.929ms
[16.945s][info][gc] GC(28) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 4280M->4281M(6538M) 460.913ms
[18.490s][info][gc] GC(29) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 4566M->4568M(6790M) 493.803ms
[20.083s][info][gc] GC(30) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 4866M->4868M(6790M) 491.910ms
[21.516s][info][gc] GC(31) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 5164M->5166M(6790M) 486.847ms
[22.895s][info][gc] GC(32) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 5462M->5464M(6790M) 443.031ms
[24.342s][info][gc] GC(33) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 5760M->5762M(6942M) 475.235ms
[25.258s][info][gc] GC(24) Pause Remark 5988M->5988M(6942M) 0.794ms
```

```
[25.827s][info][gc] GC(34) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 6066M->6067M(6942M) 458.463ms
[27.021s][info][gc] GC(35) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 6370M->6372M(6942M) 448.794ms
[27.485s][info][gc] GC(24) Pause Cleanup 6484M->6484M(6942M) 28.631ms
[27.490s][info][gc] GC(24) Concurrent Cycle 16000.856ms
[28.250s][info][gc] GC(36) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 6675M->6676M(7024M) 481.748ms
[29.651s][info][gc] GC(37) To-space exhausted
[29.651s][info][gc] GC(37) Pause Initial Mark (G1 Evacuation Pause) 6983M->7127M(7168M) 751.288ms
[29.651s][info][gc] GC(38) Concurrent Cycle
[30.135s][info][gc] GC(39) To-space exhausted
[30.135s][info][gc] GC(39) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 7168M->7168M(7168M) 203.578ms
[30.205s][info][gc] GC(40) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 7168M->7168M(7168M) 69.831ms
[53.924s][info][gc] GC(41) Pause Full (Allocation Failure) 7168M->6955M(7168M) 23719.072ms
[53.924s][info][gc] GC(38) Concurrent Cycle 24273.544ms
[54.654s][info][gc] GC(42) To-space exhausted
[54.654s][info][gc] GC(42) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 7167M->7167M(7168M) 484.771ms
[54.811s][info][gc] GC(43) Pause Initial Mark (G1 Evacuation Pause) 7167M->7167M(7168M) 156.984ms
[54.811s][info][gc] GC(44) Concurrent Cycle
[75.187s][info][gc] GC(45) Pause Full (Allocation Failure) 7167M->7166M(7168M) 20375.807ms
[75.187s][info][gc] GC(44) Concurrent Cycle 20375.993ms
[75.197s][info][gc] GC(46) To-space exhausted
[75.197s][info][gc] GC(46) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 7167M->7167M(7168M) 8.585ms
[75.199s][info][gc] GC(47) Pause Initial Mark (G1 Evacuation Pause) 7167M->7167M(7168M) 1.773ms
[75.199s][info][gc] GC(48) Concurrent Cycle
[95.382s][info][gc] GC(49) Pause Full (Allocation Failure) 7167M->7167M(7168M) 20183.050ms
[115.575s][info][gc] GC(50) Pause Full (Allocation Failure) 7167M->7167M(7168M) 20192.989ms
[115.575s][info][gc] GC(48) Concurrent Cycle 40376.227ms
[115.581s][info][gc] GC(51) Pause Young (G1 Evacuation Pause) 7167M->7167M(7168M) 2.649ms
[115.613s][info][gc] GC(52) Pause Initial Mark (G1 Evacuation Pause) 7167M->7167M(7168M) 0.629ms
[115.613s][info][gc] GC(53) Concurrent Cycle
[119.694s][info][gc] GC(54) Pause Full (Allocation Failure) 7167M->0M(8M) 4080.414ms
[119.694s][info][gc] GC(53) Concurrent Cycle 4080.622ms
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedList.linkBefore(LinkedList.java:162)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.add(LinkedList.java:952)
    at test.Tmp.main(Tmp.java:32)
```

Note the reported pauses at `[53.924s]`, `[75.187s]`, `[95.382s]`, and `[115.575s]` of over 20 seconds each…

Comment: It is missing "import java.util.*;". Which may be obvious but for a convenient copy-paste...

Comment: It’s standard on Stackoverflow, to only include imports if necessary for disambiguation. Sophisticated developments tools (Eclipse, for example) will create the imports when you paste such code fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a jshell script which creates what G1GC calls *humongous* objects which automatically bypass Eden and Survivor space.  Humongous allocations are allocations that are larger than 50% of the region size (HeapRegionSize) in G1.

You can find the code it here

[GCAllocationTest.jsh](https://github.com/bschoening/gc_log/blob/main/GCAllocationTest.jsh)