# How to cause a very high heap fragmentation in Java 8 HotSpot using CMS GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot, concurrent-mark-sweep

I am studying Java8 HotSpot heap fragmentation (on CMS), and I'm struggling to write some code that produces high fragmentation. I've been trying with very large objects without success.

Could someone post a code that creates a very high heap fragmentation (that reaches a promotion failure), so I could study it ?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose, when you take the code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49819738/2711488) and add random deletions after filling a significant part of the heap, you could get to that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [HeapFragger](https://github.com/giltene/HeapFragger) by Gil Tene from Azul systems.

It is tool build to demonstrate flaws in HotSpot JVM garbage collection.